# VBA: Not Recognizing Both My Functions Simultaneously

Tags: excel

I have a macro that spits out emails with text pulled from excel. The macro has two functions. The first is to paste the excel data into the body of the email, the second function pastes my email signature into the macro. See code below.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sig As Range

    Sheets("DMR").Select
    Range("$A$3:$T$100").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Sheets("Daily Maturing Repo").Range("G1").Value

    Set rng = Sheets("DMR").Range("A3:I100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set sig = Sheets("Signatures").Range("B1:B8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
        vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next

    strHtml = "Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please confirm the below reverse repo activity for today." & "<br>" '"<html>" & "<body>" & "Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please confirm the below activity for today." & "<br>"
    stringHtml = "<br>" & "Thank you," & "<br>"

    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Range("D2")
        .CC = "xx@xyz.com"
        .Subject = "Reverse Repo Activity - " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DMR").Range("G1")
        .HTMLBody = strHtml & RngtoHTML(rng) & stringHtml & SignaturetoHTML(sig)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Sheets("DMR").Cells.AutoFilter

End Sub

Function RngtoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim rngCl As Range
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

     'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

     'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RngtoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RngtoHTML = Replace(RngtoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
    "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function

Function SignaturetoHTML(sig As Range)

    Dim fso1 As Object
    Dim ts1 As Object
    Dim TempFile1 As String
    Dim TempWB1 As Workbook
    TempFile1 = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

     'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    sig.Copy
    Set TempWB1 = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB1.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

     'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB1.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile1, _
        Sheet:=TempWB1.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts1 = fso1.GetFile(TempFile1).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    SignaturetoHTML = ts1.ReadAll
    ts1.Close
    SignaturetoHTML = Replace(SignaturetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
    "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB1.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile1

    Set ts1 = Nothing
    Set fso1 = Nothing
    Set TempWB1 = Nothing

End Function
```

For some reason, my macro is only spitting out one of the function "results" in the HTML Body. If I delete one (e.g. RngHTML) the other (e.g. SignatureHTML) will work and vice versa, but for some reason they are not working simultaneously. What's confusing me is that both of them obviously work, it's just they won't work at the same time if that makes sense. Any suggestions? Let me know if you need clarification on anything.

Comment: Have you placed a stop on `.HTMLBody = strHtml & RngtoHTML(rng) & stringHtml & SignaturetoHTML(sig)` and stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes, it opens a new workbook for both and pastes the data I need in each of those workbooks. However, only one (just RngHTML's results in this case) will paste into the body of the email. If I take out RngHTML and just leave SignatureHTML that one will paste into the email body.